# Sort list of names from a text file

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::ifstream;
using std::string;

int main()
{
    ifstream NameList("LineUp.txt");

    string List = "LineUp.txt";

    while (getline(NameList, List))
    {
        std::vector<string> names = {List};

        std::sort(names.begin(), names.end());
    }
    NameList.close();
    
    return 0;
    }
```

I know that I am supposed to put "[] (string a, string b)" at the end of the sort command but my IDE tells me to remove the "string" identifier, or any identifier I have, and then it can't identify a or b.

I want to sort by alphabet.

Comment: Do you realize that `names` will only ever have one item? Did you mean to declare your vector outside of the loop and `.push_back` or similar on each iteration?

Comment: Why do you know that you need a custom ordering function? The default string ordering already is lexicographical (i.e. in "alphabetical order").

Comment: Post the code that is giving you errors instead of trying to describe it.

Comment: I am doing an assignment where I need to sort a list of names in alphabetical order using c++. I didn't think I'd need .push_back because I have a string of the list with all the names already.

Answer (score 4):

```cpp
std::vector<string> names = {List};
```

This vector only lives in the scope of the `while` loop. That means, you are creating a new vector for each single line that is read.

You then sort this vector, which is quite useless, since
a) it contains only one line and
b) you do nothing else with it and it gets destroyed at the closing `}`

Solution:

1. move the vector to before the while loop
2. move the sort() call to after the while loop
3. inside the loop, call `names.push_back()` in order to add the current line to the list

Things will go much smoother if your variables have the correct names as well. `List` should not be named like that, because it's used in `getline()`, so it's just one line of the list. `NameList` should be named `file`, because that's what you access. The list with the names is the vector.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::ifstream;
using std::string;

int main()
{
    ifstream file("LineUp.txt");
    std::vector<string> names;
    string line;
    while (getline(file, line))
    {
        names.push_back(line);
    }
    std::sort(names.begin(), names.end());
    file.close();

    for (auto& name : names)
    {
        std::cout << name << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm on the right track now. It is sorting alphabetically, but it is just displaying the first name of the list.

Comment: @Zer0Sp4c3: use a `for (auto& line:names)` loop

Comment: How would I do that? I am fairly new to coding and am just learning how to do all of this.

Comment: Thank you!!! You've been a big help, thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome. I rolled back the question to version 1, since the edit would invalidate my answer. On Stack Overflow, please do not edit your question in a way that existing answers would require to be rewritten. If the **one problem** that you have described first has been solved, leave it like that. If you have a follow-up question, ask a new question. It's not like a forum where you'd have a thread and the thread continues until **all your problems** are solved.

Comment: I understand, will do next time

Comment: @Zer0Sp4c3: see my updated code. My fault: you can't use the name `line` again, because it's used before